# find similar rows in a text file in unix system

Tags: unix

I have a file named `tt.txt` and the contents of this file is as follows:

```
fdgs
jhds
fdgs
```

I am trying to get the similar row as the output in a text file.

my expected output is:

```
fdgs
fdgs
```

to do so, I used this command:

```
uniq -u tt.txt > output.txt
```

but it returns:

```
fdgs
jhds
fdgs
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, I do. Anything else you want to know?

Comment: Why did you choose `-u`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by similar row you mean the row with the same content.

From the uniq [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) the uniq command would only filter the adjacent matching lines from the repeated lines. So you need to sort the input first and used -D option to print all duplicated lines like below. However -D options is limited to the GNU implementation, and doing this would print the output in different order from the input.

> sort tt.txt  | uniq -D

If you want the output to be in the same order you need to remember the input line number and sort the line number again like this

> cat -n tt.txt  | sort -k 2 | uniq -f 1 -D | sort -k 1,1   | sed 's/\s+[0-9]+\s+//'

- cat -n would print the content with the line number
- sort -k 2 would sort the input starting at 2rd column
- uniq -f 1 would ignore the first column
- sort -k1,1 would sort the the output back by the original line number
- sed 's/\s+[0-9]+\s+//' would delete the first column with line number

uniq -u command would output only the unique input line, which is completely opposite as what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One in awk:

```
$ awk '++seen[$0]==2;seen[$0]>1' file
fdgs
fdgs
```